# Change 3rd and 4th delimeters in every line from a comma to a pipe with (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a file with about 30 or 40 lines. The file looks similiar to this:

```
1234567899,05/30/13,1430,10,ANDERSON MONTE
4567891234,06/01/13,930,10,ANDERSON JENNIFER
7891234567,06/02/13,1515,10,ANDERSON MONTE
```

Now, I need to change the comma in ever line around the time to pipes. I also need to change it from 24 hour time to 12 hour with the AM or PM behind it. I am reading all this from a file and not from a database unfortunately. So I need it to end up looking like this:

```
1234567899,05/30/13|02:30PM|10,ANDERSON MONTE
4567891234,06/01/13|09:30AM|10,ANDERSON JENNIFER
7891234567,06/02/13|03:15PM|10,ANDERSON MONTE
```

Any help would be appreciated. I would like to use PHP if possible.  It started out as a report that I've been able to strip down to the above.

Thank you in advance.
Monte

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have been able to take it to a text file using PHP to the first instance I gave above. However I have not done anything further to get it to what I need in the second one as I'm lost and pretty much not sure how to change those commas into the pipes, or for that matter to change the time into the correct format.  Forgive me as I'm still pretty new to this... Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if date and time always come second and third, one solution for sure would be to use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice), [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) and [`join`/`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
array_splice($arr, 1, 3, join('|', array_slice($arr, 1, 3));
```

---

Here's the full code (but stackoverflow exists to *help* you solve your problems, not to solve your problems):

```
$in = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
$out = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while(($line = fgetcsv($in)) !== FALSE) {
  # you're probably better off using methods of the DateTime class:
  $hours = substr($line[2], 0, -2);
  $line[2] = (($hours+12-1)%12+1) . substr($line[2], -2) . (($hours<12)?'AM':'PM');

  array_splice($line, 1, 3, join('|', array_slice($line, 1, 3));

  $fputcsv($out, $line);
}
```

Comment: Please forgive me knittl, but I guess I'm lost.. My main file that I'm reading is final_text.txt... How would I go about using the above code in a new php line?
Thank you so much,
Monte

Comment: Read the file, loop over each line, split by comma (or use fgetcsv function), use my code, write to new file

Comment: Thank you knittl.. I've made some minor changes, but I was really struggling with the | line.  Thanks again, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$files = file("log.txt");
$list = array();

foreach ( $files as $data ) {
    $data = explode(",", $data);
    $time = sprintf("%s|%s|%s", 
            $data[1], 
            DateTime::createFromFormat("Gi", str_pad($data[2], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT))->format("h:iA"), 
            $data[3]);
    $list[] = implode(",", array($data[0],$time,$data[4]));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1234567899,05/30/13|02:30PM|10,ANDERSON MONTE

    [1] => 4567891234,06/01/13|09:30AM|10,ANDERSON JENNIFER

    [2] => 7891234567,06/02/13|03:15PM|10,ANDERSON MONTE
)
```

Comment: So I could use the above, however I need to to write to another file. I had been using the command: file_put_contents("final_file.txt", "$str);

in order to create the new file, am I on the right track with that?

Thank you
Monte

Comment: This also only gave me the first one in the list when I did a print_r command. So it didn't loop through the file like it was supposed to.  I really appreciate your help on this.
Thanks again,
Monte

Comment: While I got this to work it's not working completely. I do have it dumping into a file like I mentioned above, however it's only dumping in the first full line and part of the second. I get what looks like the following:<br /> 1234567899,05/30/13|02:30PM|10,ANDERSON MONTE <br /> 4567891234 <br />And that's all I get